# How to use a character to quit a loop in c Language?

Tags: c

**How to use q as character to  exit ?**
How to use q as a quit to this code. It loops till it gets the ASCII values of q.
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int pos=0,neg=0,zero=0,i=0,num;
  printf("Input numbers.");
  scanf("%d",&num);
  for(i=0;num!="q";i++)
  {

      if(num>0)
      {
          pos++;
      }
      if(num<0)
      {
          neg++;
      }
      if(num==0)
      {
          zero++;
      }
  }
  printf("You entered \n\tpositive number::: %d times\nNegative number:::%d times\nZero:::%d times",pos,neg,zero);


}
```

`

Comment: You mean, you want the program to `printf("You entered \n\tpositive number::: %d ....)` and then quit, after the user typed 'q' in the terminal? If its the case you have to ask for input inside of the loop, i am sure you can figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the scanf line inside the loop.

```
for(i=0;num!="q";i++)
{
  scanf("%d",&num);
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d",&num);      /*     <-- for initializing num before using    */
for(i=0;num!='q';i++)  /*     <-- compare with 'q' and not with "q"    */
{
     scanf("%d",&num); /*     <-- take input                           */
     //your code 
}
```

Comapare with `'q'` (*character*) and not with string literal `"q"` which comparises of `'q'` and `'\0'` (***take note of single quotes***).

And also you need to take input inside loop , or *else value of* `num` *does not change in loop* .

Answer (score 0):

Try changing for to while and place scanf inside loop.

```
scanf("%d",&num);
while(num!="q")
{
    if(num>0)
    {
        pos++;
    }
    if(num<0)
    {
        neg++;
    }
    if(num==0)
    {
        zero++;
    }
    scanf("%d",&num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should actually loop:

```
while(1) { // infinite loop
 ...
}
```

... then scan for integers inside the loop:

```
while(1) { // infinite loop
 scanf("%d",&num)
 ...
};
```

... then remember that, oops, the user can enter "q" that is *not* a number

```
while(1) { // infinite loop
 char input[100];
 scanf("%s", input);
 if( strcmp( input, "q" ) == 0 ) {
     break;
 }
 else {
    sscanf( input, "%d", &num); 
 }
 ...
}
```

... then add your tests

```
   while(1) { // infinite loop
     char input[100];
     scanf("%s", input);
     if( strcmp( input, "q" ) == 0 ) {
         break;
     }
     else {
        sscanf( input, "%d", &num); 
     }

     if(num>0) {
        pos++;
     }
     if(num<0) {
        neg++;
     }
     if(num==0) {
        zero++;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
int fldCnt = scanf("%d", &num);
while (fldCnt == 1)
{
    // your code
    fldCnt = scanf("%d", &num);
}
```

When you enter a "q", zero fields get converted to `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int pos=0, neg=0, zero=0;
    int i, ch, num;

    printf("Input numbers.\n");
    do {
        while(1 == scanf("%d", &num)){//input into inside loop
            if(num > 0)
                pos++;
            else if(num < 0)
                neg++;
            else //if(num==0)
                zero++;
        }
        ch = getchar();//q not allow `scanf("%d", &num)`
    } while(ch != 'q' && ch != EOF);
    printf("You entered \n\tpositive number:::%d times\n\tNegative number:::%d times\n\tZero:::%d times\n",pos,neg,zero);
}
```